# Django UpdateView, get the current object being edit id?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to get the current record being edited's id, but am failing thus far. my view is as per the below:

views.py

```
class EditSite(UpdateView):
    model = SiteData
    form_class = SiteForm
    template_name = "sites/site_form.html"

    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('config.edit_subnet')))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.site_id = self.object.pk
        return super(EditSite, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
            return reverse_lazy("sites:site_overview", args=(self.site_id,))

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['SiteID']=self.site_id
        context['SiteName']=self.location
        context['FormType']='Edit'

        return context
```

and the error:

```
File "/itapp/itapp/sites/views.py" in dispatch
  890.         self.site_id = self.object.pk

Exception Type: AttributeError at /sites/site/edit/7
Exception Value: 'EditSite' object has no attribute 'object'
```

ive tried:

```
self.object.pk
object.pk
self.pk
```

Comment: use `get_object().id` instead of `object.id`

Comment: am now getting, name get_object() is not defined

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The view's object attribute is set during get/post by BaseUpdateView:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    return super(BaseUpdateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    return super(BaseUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

So it is not yet available in the `dispatch` method. 
**But** it will be available in the `get_success_url` and `get_context_data` methods as those happen after get/post. So you could do:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

class EditSite(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = SiteData
    form_class = SiteForm
    template_name = "sites/site_form.html"
    permission_required = 'config.edit_subnet'

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
        return reverse_lazy("sites:site_overview", args=(self.object.site_id,))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['SiteID']=self.object.site_id
        context['SiteName']=self.location # <--- where does self.location come from? self.object.location perhaps?
        context['FormType']='Edit'
        return context
```

Comment: am getting the errorr Generic detail view EditSite must be called with either an object pk or a slug.

Comment: Your url conf for the view must include capturing either a pk or slug parameter as these are expected by the view: [how-to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#example)

Comment: like for `self.get_object`

Comment: Can someone please help me here. I think this question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387712/how-to-createview-updateview-using-foreign-key-in-nested-model